# jQuery Date Picker is bigger than the preview site

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to test the jQuery calendar tool, but it [appears to be too big](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/8167/datepicker.png),
bigger than the [preview page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be that it is indeed the font sizes and related that are making the size too big - but I'm still trying to figure out the best solution, as I'd like it to look like it does in the jQuery demo site - their css seems to be the same -_-

Comment: I found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812401/jquery-data-picker-font-size-issue/8812568#8812568

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  I had to change the font sizes in the custom CSS to something other than 1.25em.  I believe that I used small as that was what I used elsewhere in my app.

While browsing the page in FireFox, I was able to inspect the entire calendar control in FireBug and change the font-size to medium (I think, maybe small) and it rendered perfectly at that point.  Just went into the UI CSS and permanently changed it and no complaints since.

Check out [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656676/jquery-ui-theming-css-sizing-differences)...

Answer (score 9):

In the css file change the font-size e.g. my css file happens to be

```
/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css
```

and I changed

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

to

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just add this css line:

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    font-size:12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebug's Inspect feature](http://getfirebug.com/) to select one of the values and you will see what stylesheets sets the size of the font. Then you can change it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with the css styles that jquery is using (This is tying in with everyone else's answer about the css), especially the font-size being in em compared to px - I think it is trying to inherit styles from the page itself, or something like that.

For me, the solution was to change the ui-widget css class's font-size to 11px, resulting in the following css class:

```
.ui-widget {
-x-system-font:none;
font-family:Trebuchet MS,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
**font-size:11px;**
font-size-adjust:none;
font-stretch:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific CSS that adjusts the font size? That would adjust any jQuery font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that a stylesheet is controlling this.  Looking at the source of the web page, it is either [this one](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css) or [this one](http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css).

As you can see, they are pretty ugly as is, but you can run it through a prettifier like [this one](http://flumpcakes.co.uk/css/optimiser/).

Or you can simply download a version of JQuery UI that has the lightness theme in it.  My guess is that it has the correct sizes in it already.

Comment: This didn't help - the design stayed the same :P

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are using the same jQueryUI theme that the demo site is using.  I have seen this exact problem by having the wrong theme loaded on my site.

Comment: Yup, it's the right css file that is being loaded - the colors etc. are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your css line:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; }
font-size: 0.7em;
```

like this:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; font-size: 0.7em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I resolved it by inspecting the elements using chrome's developer tool and realized that the div element containing the datepicker (i.e. the div with id `ui-datepicker-div`) got appended to the `body` element. The datepicker div has it's `font-size` css attribute set to `1.1em` (from the class `ui-widget` in the base css file from jQuery UI). Since I had not set a font-size on the `body` element (i.e. the element containing the datepicker) it defaults to using `16px` according to [this blog](http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/). Setting an explicit `font-size` on the body element resolved the issue for me.